# unix extract multiple lines

Tags: sed

I have the following file:

```
$cat somefile
Line1 T:10 Hello
   Var1 = value1
   Var2 = value2

Line2 T:2 Where
   VarX1 = ValueX1
   VarX2 = ValueX2

Line3 T:10 AAAA
   Var10 = Val1
   Var11 = Val11

Line4 T:10 ABCC
   Var101 = Val110
```

...
What I need is by giving the search criteria, it should get multiple lines.
For example, if the search criteria is -- T:10 -- then it should give

```
Line1 T:10 Hello
   Var1 = value1
   Var2 = value2

Line3 T:10 AAAA
   Var10 = Val1
   Var11 = Val11
```

I tried the sed command

```
sed -ne '/T:10/,/^$/p' somefile
```

But this is not working properly, it is getting other lines too sometimes.
Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your example output is confusing to me. Why don't you think the Line4 T:10 won't print, becuase your `/^$`/ range match terminator? Also, it  will help if you are showing us the exact output you *do* get. Finally, it works for me as I would expect, given your data and sed script. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "paragraph" grep. Linux/GNU grep doesn't have a paragraph mode and I haven't done it in sed, but you can use perl.

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if /T:10/' somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `bash` solution

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(<file)
search="T:10"
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS="|"
data=(${data//$'\n\n'/|})
for i in "${!data[@]}"
do
    case "${data[$i]}" in
     *"${search}"* ) echo "$i : ${data[$i]}" ;;
    esac
done
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/T:10/{:a;N;/^$/M!ba;p}' file
```

Turn off automatic printing by using the `-n` option. Gather up lines between `T:10` and an empty line and print them otherwise do not.